# Traverse and count directory paths

Tags: javascript, path, counter, traversal

I have a flat list of directories:

```
var directories = [
    { path: '/a', status: 0 },
    { path: '/a/a', status: 1 },
    { path: '/a/b', status: 1 },
    { path: '/a/c', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b/a', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b/b', status: 1 },
    { path: '/c', status: 0 },
    { path: '/c/a', status: 2 },
    { path: '/c/b', status: 0 },
    { path: '/c/c', status: 1 },
    { path: '/c/d', status: 1 },
    { path: '/d', status: 0 },
    { path: '/d/a', status: 1 },
    { path: '/e', status: 1 },
    { path: '/e/a', status: 0 }
];
```

I would like to have the total children of each directory and the totals of those childrens by their status number e.g.

```
{ path: '/a', status: 0, child_total: 3, child_status-0: 1, child_status-1: 2 }
```

I believe the best way to do this is to create an Object containing named paths, then loop through each parent of a directory and add one to each total.

Using this approach I've created these functions:

```
function increment(item, attr) {
    if (!item[attr]) { item[attr] = 0; }
    item[attr] += 1;
};

function calculate(items) {
    var i = 0;
    var list = {};
    // for each directory
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        // if the directory stats already exist, merge in directory info
        list[items[i].path] = list[items[i].path] ? Object.assign(list[items[i].path], items[i]) : items[i];
        var j = 0;
        var parts = items[i].path.split('/');
        var path = '';
        // loop through it's parents
        for (j = 1; j < parts.length; j += 1) {
            path += '/' + parts[j];
            // increment the parent's totals
            if (path !== items[i].path) {
                if (!list[path]) { list[path] = {}; }
                increment(list[path], 'child_total');
                increment(list[path], 'child_status-' + items[i].status);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/b955d3mb/1/

This is the directory browser I'm looking to use the structure on:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/x93pcd60/

I'm planning to run this function on thousands of items so performance is very important. I'm wondering if this is the best approach?

Is there a better way? without a loop within a loop? Maybe a RegEx for splitting the paths?

Any suggestions would help!

Comment: Why is `child_total` for `path:"/a"` `3`?

Comment: are you need only for top-level parent paths to be processed?

Comment: /a has 3 children /a/a, /a/b and /a/c. I will need all levels processed eventually, but only one level is shown at a time e.g. nested directory structure

Comment: Why is `status` for `path:"/a"` `0`?

Comment: each directory has it's own status e.g. 0 = 'added', 1 = 'deleted', 2 = 'ignored'

Comment: @KimT Why does the resulting object have a `status` set to `0` though the `status` for each object which has a path ending in `"/a"`, that is `"/a/a"`, `"/a/b"`, `"/a/c"`, is `1`, `1`, `0`, respectively?

Comment: sub-directories may have status of added/deleted = 1/2, but the parent hasn't been changed itself. It's status is independent of it's children.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way? without a loop within a loop? Maybe a RegEx for
>   splitting the paths?

Not sure how to determine what "a better way" is. Only you can make such a determination.

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to iterate each object in original array, accrue data about the object at an object.

Substituted an array of `statuses` where property is the current path and `status` is the `status` for the current object, for `child_status-0: 1, child_status-N: 2` properties.

```js
var directories = [
    { path: '/a', status: 0 },
    { path: '/a/a', status: 1 },
    { path: '/a/b', status: 1 },
    { path: '/a/c', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b/a', status: 0 },
    { path: '/b/b', status: 1 },
    { path: '/c', status: 0 },
    { path: '/c/a', status: 2 },
    { path: '/c/b', status: 0 },
    { path: '/c/c', status: 1 },
    { path: '/c/d', status: 1 },
    { path: '/d', status: 0 },
    { path: '/d/a', status: 1 },
    { path: '/e', status: 1 },
    { path: '/e/a', status: 0 }
];

let pathData = directories.reduce((paths, {path, status}) => {

  let dir = new URL("http://mock" + path);
  let pathnames = dir.pathname.match(/[^/]+/g); 
  let _path = pathnames[0];

  if (!paths.hasOwnProperty(_path)) {
    paths[_path] = {child_total:0, statuses:[]}
  } 

  paths[_path].statuses.push({[dir.pathname]:status});

  if (pathnames.length > 1) {
    paths[_path].child_total += 1;
  };
  
  return paths;
}, {});

console.log(pathData);
```

Comment: hmm not exactly what I'm aiming for, I need to know at the parent level the total number of children with status: 0, or status: 1. Reduce looks like an interesting approach, but as each value doesn't always relate to previous it might not be any more efficient